# c# two namespaces with the same name

Tags: c#, selenium, namespaces, resources, using

I am working on a Project that uses Selenium directory with using statement:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
```

Now I have added a reference to the project that also using this directory but extending it.

when I wrote the following line of code:
[image]

I get no compilation errors but an exception on running time saying:
"Method not found" exception:
[image]

How can I force and make the program use the new extended selenium directive in this instance and methods use and not the old version where those methods are not exist?

Thank you

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text messages or code. Post the text of the message in your question so that it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
using RemoteWebDriverExtended=global::Open.Qa.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriverExtended
...
RemoteWebDriverExtended Driver = new RemoteWebDriverExtended(...)
```

Comment: Thanks Gevorg, I tried that but it is not working. still - Method not found on runtime